# Need help interpreting a passage from an old text on Diophantine equations

Tags: diophantine-equations, self-learning

I need help interpreting this passage from page 35 of the book Diophantine Analysis by Robert D Carmichael.

"Thus the problem of solving Eq. (1) is reduced to that of solving Eq. (4) for $u$ and $v$ and choosing one of those values for which x and y have the desired characteristic.  **But the problem of solving Eq. (4) is identical with that of the representation of a given integer by means of a binary quadratic form.**  The plan of this book does not permit the detailed development of this latter subject."

Equation 1 is $ax^2+2bxy+cy^2+2dx+2ey+f=0$ and equation 4 is $au^2+2buv+cv^2=m$.  $u,v,$ and $m$ are defined elsewhere if that matters, but what I need to know is what that bold part is referring to; and that last sentence gives me little reason to believe I can find context in the book to make sense of it.

This is the main part of the book I'm interested in, but I do intend to go through most of it.  It wasn't easy to find a book on the subject and I just checked it out from the library today.

Comment: If we define $f(u,v) = au^2 + 2b uv + cv^2$, then $f$ is a [binary quadratic form](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_quadratic_form) (a homogeneous polynomial of degree 2 in two variables). So solving $f(u,v)=m$ is equivalent to the question "what integers are in the image of $f$?" (that is, what integers can be 'represented' by the form $f$?). This is a classic subject that has roots in work of Fermat and of [Brahmagupta](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brahmagupta%27s_identity).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A [binary quadratic form](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_quadratic_form) is a homogeneous polynomial of degree 2 in two variables, 
$$q(x,y) = ax^2 + bxy + cy^2.$$

When $a,b,c\in\mathbb{Z}$, we can view $q$ as a function $q\colon\mathbb{Z}\times\mathbb{Z}\to\mathbb{Z}$, a common question asks for a description of the elements of the image. For instance, there is the classic problem of determining which integers can be written as the sum of two squares; this can be viewed as asking for the image of the binary quadratic form $q(x,y) = x^2+y^2$ (that is, $a=c=1$, $b=0$). The classic terminology is that an integer $m$ is "represented" by the binary quadratic form $q$ if and only if there exist integers (sometimes *positive integers*) $r$ and $s$ such that $q(r,s)=m$.

This subject has deep roots; they go back to Fermat (who described all primes that can be represented by $q(x,y)=x^2+y^2$, $q(x,y) = x^2+2y^2$, and $q(x,y)=x^2+3y^2$), Euler (who proved Fermat's assertions and then attempted to extend them to other quadratic forms $q(x,y) = x^2+dy^2$ with $d$ squarefree), Lagrange, and Gauss (who dedicates the entire Part V of his *Disquisitiones Arithmeticae* to the study of these functions). They also reach into the East: [Brahmagupta's identity](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brahmagupta%27s_identity), for example, shows that if $m$ and $n$ can both be represented by the quadratic form $q(x,y) = x^2+cy^2$, then so can $mn$ (that is, the set of representable integers is closed under products).

What the book is saying is that, via a change of variable, solving the general two-variable quadratic diophantine equation
$$ax^2 + bxy + cy^2 + dx + ey + f = 0\tag{1}$$
is equivalent to the question of determining when a certain integer $m$ is representable by a particular binary quadratic form (where $m$ and the quadratic form depends on $a$, $b$, $c$, $d$, $e$, and $f$); in the sense that solving the diophantine equation $(1)$ yields a representation of $m$; and a representation of $m$ gives a solution to $(1)$.

The subject of quadratic forms is rich and interesting; [whole books have been written on the subject by great minds](https://www.maa.org/EbusPPRO/DynamicSearch/ProductDetailsAdvancedSearch/tabid/176/ProductId/1571/Default.aspx); the *Disquisitiones* spends more time on them than on everything else put together. Whether an integer can be represented by a binary quadratic form is intimately connected with the arithmetic of quadratic fields. There is a beautiful [Theorem of Conway and Schneeberger] that says that and integral quadratic form with integer matrix that represents the positive integers between 1 and 15 will, in fact, represent *all* integers. And much more.

But because it is rich and interesting, it is too complicated to get into in any detail in a book that is not devoted to them. Hence, your book is saying that this is a little too hard to get into in detail.

Answer (score 1):

The point is that, by a linear change of variables, one can *normalize* the non-homogeneous equation to *homogenous* form. In fact one can go normalize to Pell form - see below. Such normalization is important since it brings to the fore the innate linearity - making it easier to exploit the relationship between binary quadratic forms and ideals or modules - see below.

Lagrange showed how to reduce a general binary quadratic Diophatine equation to Pell form.

$$\rm a\ x^2 + b\ xy + c\ y^2 + d\ x + e\ y + f\ =\ 0 $$

reduces to a Pell equation as follows: put $\rm\ D = b^2-4ac,\ E = bd-2ae,\ F = d^2-4af\:.\ $ Then

$$\rm  D\ Y^2\ =\ (D\ y + E)^2 + D\ F - E^2,\quad\quad Y\ =\ 2ax + by + d $$

Therefore if we put $\rm\quad\ \ X\: =\: D\ y + E,\quad\ \ N\: =\: E^2 - D\ F\quad\ \ $ we obtain the Pell equation

$$\rm X^2 - D\ Y^2\ =\ N $$

Below is a proof of the standard equivalences between forms, ideals and numbers, excerpted from section 5.2, p. 225 of Henri Cohen's book "A course in computational algebraic number theory".

[image]
[image]

Comment: This is way over my head.  I don't know what an ideal is (probably look it up later), what SL$_2$ is, or what that "/" in the notation means.  What topic does all this fall under if I wanted to look into it?

Comment: @Mike The topic is Algebraic Number Theory. In particular, these topics are best understood by studying [quadratic number fields.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadratic_integer) For an introduction requiring no knowledge of university algebra see Hardy and Wright, or Stark's *An Introduction to Number Theory*. If you know some university algebra then Harvey Cohn's *Advanced Number Theory* (Dover) goes much further.

Comment: I don't see either of those titles available at any libraries I have access to.  I did find something on ideals in my brother's old textbook, A First Course in Abstract Algebra by John B. Fraleigh.  I may not have had as in depth a course as he did, but I did help with a lot of the homework, so hopefully it will all come back quickly.  But what exactly does SL$_2$ signify?