# Find $N$ when $N(N - 101)$ is the square of a positive integer

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Let $N$ be a positive integer such that $N(N - 101)$ is the square of a
positive integer. Then determine the value of $N$.

OR
determine all possible values of $N$.

Is the fact that 101 is a prime number of any use?

Comment: the title seems unappropriate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only solutions are
$n=51^2$ and $n=0$
(if you allow that).
Here is the reason:

Let's look at the general case
where we want
$n(n-a)$ to be a square.
Then
$m^2 = n(n-a)
=n^2-na$.

If $a$ is even,
say $a = 2b$,
then
$m^2 = n^2-2bn$,
so
$m^2+b^2
=n^2-2bn+b^2
=(n-b)^2
$
so
$b^2
=(n-b)^2-m^2
=(n-b-m)(n-b+m)
$
so that each factorization of $b^2 = uv$
produces a possible solution.
We get
$u = n-b-m$ and
$v = n-b+m$,
so
$u+v = 2n-2b$
or
$n = (u+v)/2+b$.
For this to be an integer,
$u$ and $v$
must have the same parity
(i.e., both even
or both odd).

If $a$ is odd,
multiplying by $4$ and adding $a^2$
(doing this is due to my experience
in these type of problems),
we get
$4m^2+a^2
=4n^2-4na+a^2
= (2n-a)^2
$
so
$a^2 
=(2n-a)^2-4m^2
=(2n-a)^2-(2m)^2
=(2n-a-2m)(2n-a+2m)
$.

Looking at the factors of $a^2$,
for each $a^2 = uv$,
we get the equations
$u = 2n-a-2m$ 
and
$v = 2n-a+2m$
which we can solve for $n$ and $m$.
In particular,
this shows that
for any $a$ there are only
a finite number of $n$
such that
$n(n-a)$ is a square,
and all the possibilities
can be gotten from
factoring $a^2$.

If $a$ is prime,
as in this case,
the only factorizations are
$1*a^2$ and $a*a$.

In the first case,
$2n-a-2m = 1$
and 
$2n-a+2m=a^2$.
Adding these,
$4n-2a = a^2+1$
so
$4n=a^2+2a+1
=(a+1)^2
$
or
$n = ((a+1)/2)^2
$.
Then
$2m = 2n-a-1
=(a+1)^2/2-a-1
=(a^2+2a+1-2a-2)/2
=(a^2-1)/2
$,
so
$m = (a^2-1)/4$.

As a check,
$n(n-a)
=((a+1)^2/4)((a+1)^2/4-a)
=((a+1)^2/4)((a-1)^2/4)
=((a+1)(a-1)/4)^2
=((a^2-1)/4)^2
$

In the second case,
$2n-a-2m = a$
and 
$2n-a+2m=a$.
This means $m = 0$
so that
$n = a$.

For $a=101$,
the results are
$n=51^2 = 2601
$
(so $n(n-101)
=2601*2500
=(51*50)^2
$)
and
$n=101$
(when the product is zero,
which *is* a square).

Comment: I am confused at $4n-2a=2a^2$.

Comment: That was a mistake (a specialty of mine). Refresh and you will see a more correct answer.

Comment: 0 is not a positive integer...

Comment: @Rudstar This is a special case of **Lagrange's reduction** of a general bivariate Diophantine equation to a Pell equation (which degenerates to a difference of squares when the discriminant is a perfect square, as here). See my answer for details.

Comment: @Bill: Thanks. As I said, I knew my answer wasn't new, but I find it fun to work out results again.

Answer (score 2):

**Hint** $\ $ Completing the square reduces to checking finitely many factors

$\qquad \begin{eqnarray} n^2\!-pn\, =\, m^2\! &\smash[t]{\overset{\large \times\, 4}\iff}& (2n\!-p\!-\!2m)(2n\!-\!p+\!2m)\, =\, p^2_{\phantom{I_I}}\\
&\iff& (N-M)(N+M)\, =\, p^2,\ \ \ N,M = 2n\!-\!p,\,2m\end{eqnarray}$

whch reduces to solving for $\,N\pm M = $ factor of $\,p^2,\,$ only a *few* cases when $\,p\,$ is prime.

**Remark** $ $ This is a *standard technique* for solving bivariate Diophantine equations. Generally [Lagrange showed](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/116549/242) how to reduce $\ ax^2\!+bxy+cy^2\!+dx+ey+f = 0\ $ to $\,X^2- D Y^2\! = N,\,$ i.e. a Pell equation, where $\,D = b^2-4ac = $ discriminant. When $\,D = d^2 \,$ is a perfect square, the Pell equation degenerates to a *difference of squares* $\, X^2 - \bar Y^2\! = N,\ \ \bar Y = dY,\,$ as above with $ D = 2^2.$

Comment: Can you make how you moved in the first equality more explicit

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** Consider $\gcd (N, N-101)$. What can you say about it?

Split into cases. One case is $ \gcd(N, N-101) = 1$ and we want to solve $ a^2 - b^2 = 101$.

Answer (score 1):

Let $\displaystyle n(n-a)=(n-b)^2\iff n=\frac{b^2}{2b-a}$

If integer $d$ divides  both $b^2,2b-a$

$d$ will divide $2(b^2)-b(2b-a)=ab$

$d$ will divide $2(ab)-a(2b-a)=a^2$

So, the **necessary** condition for integer $n$ is  $2b-a$ must divide  $a^2$

Here $a=101$ which is fortunately prime